# Thread 1 breakpoint 1.1 error - swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I am working on this code. I have to display username in a textfield, but it displays an error and the application crashes.

```
//
//  TableViewControllerSettings.swift
//  Secondo B
//
//  Created by Edoardo on 16/12/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 ERC. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import Parse
import ParseUI

class TableViewControllerSettings: UITableViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.UserName.text = "Bentornato " + (PFUser.currentUser()?.username)!

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

@IBAction func Logout(sender: AnyObject) {

    PFUser.logOut()
    performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_tableLogin", sender: self)
    let alert = UIAlertView(title: "Logout", message: "Hai effettuato il logout", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
    alert.show()

}

}
```

how can I solve the problem in the line

self.UserName.text = "Bentornato" ?

t displays me an error breakpoint 1.1

Comment: Are you sure you have cell template with reuse identifier `cell` in your XIB? Also you need to implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` delegate methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare the `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate method

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    //return the number of rows
    return self.messagesArray.count
}
```